# Error al generar PDF con DomPdf

Tags: php, dompdf

## **Tengo un error al querer generar un pdf con dompdf**

Estoy usando la libreria dompdf para generar un reporte y convertirlo a pdf, descarge la libreria de forma directa y por composer, y de ambas formas me tira el mismo error: 
***!!Se ha producido un error al cargar el documento pdf*** 
Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
    include_once __DIR__ . "/../templates/nav.php";
    ob_start();

?>

<main class="main">

    <?php if(count($reporte) === 0)  {?>
        <p>No hay registros</p>
    <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="contenedor_tabla">
                    <table class="main-lita">
                        <thead class="theader">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Usuario</th>
                                <th>Fecha de Creacion</th>
                                <th>Fecha Programada</th>
                                <th>Frecuencia</th>
                                <th>Tipo</th>
                                <th>Observaciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody class="tbody">
                            <tr>
                                <?php foreach($reporte as $reportes){?>
                                    <td><?php echo $reportes->nombre;?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $reportes->usuario;?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $reportes->fechaCreacion;?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $reportes->fechaProgramada;?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $reportes->frecuencia;?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $reportes->tipo;?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $reportes->observaciones;?></td>
                                    <tr></tr>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
    <?php } ?>
</main>
<?php
$html = ob_get_clean();
// echo $html;

require_once '../library/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("archivo.pdf", array("Attachment" => true));

?>
```

No se que me falta o cual es mi error, si se descarga el pdf pero sin la informacion que quiero que contenga y directamente al abrir el pdf me sale el error previamente dicho, ya lo intente con composer y con descargar la libreria de forma directa y en ambas formas si se descarga el pdf pero sin el conteniedo marcando el mismo error.
Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Deberías probar: 1. Establecer tamaño de página antes de cargar contenido 2. Agregar las etiquetas HTML que faltan (html, head, body)

Comment: Intente ambas cosas y me sigue quedando el mismo error